# Programmatically add a views

Tags: views

I'm writing a little module which should simplify creating a new view proccess for my site manager. What I want to do is to create a form, where the editor can fill some options (like title, path, some specific values for filtering etc) and then my code has to insert those options in my view template and import it to the database like a noraml view created via UI.

But as I understood, hook_views_default_value just loads the ready view item which is conteined in the module. But i want to create a new one each time with the same template. How can i do this?

Will be very appreciated for any advice.

Comment: This sounds very interesting

Comment: You are asking how to programmatically create a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest You to check views export functionality (admin/structure/views/view/name-of-some-view/export). There you should get the view object.

Then, copy this object to your form_submit function, replace desired values with form values and call $view->save() function. The view should be created (or updated, if such machine name exist.)